# Java Swing UI breaking on action

Tags: java, swing

I have a BorderLayout set up with 3 panels, one occupying west, one center, and the third south. When I perform an action (ie mouse click in the center panel), the panel in the west shows up in the center panel, and when I click the button in the south panel it appears in the north as well. It should be noted that the components are not leaving their panel, just showing up elsewhere in the frame as well. Any idea what could be causing this? I'm currently calling repaint() to update the GUI. Should I be updating it a different way?

Here is how I am adding the panels

```
GridJPanel gp = new GridJPanel();

TextJPanel tp = new TextJPanel();
sp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
buttonsPanel.add(stepButton);

getContentPane().add(tp, BorderLayout.WEST);
getContentPane().add(gp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
getContentPane().add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setSize(700, 400);
setVisible(true);
```

This is the mouse listener that is causing the west to flip to the center. This same listener also causes the south to appear in the north.

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {

        if(ready) {
            points.removeAll(points);
            ready = false;
        }

        xP = evt.getX() / dGrid;
        yP = evt.getY() / dGrid;
        points.add(new Point2D.Float(xP, yP));
        if(points.size() == 2) {
            ready = true;
            repaint();
        }               
    }
});
```

paintComponent method

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    initgr();
    showGrid(g);

    if(ready) {
        drawLine(g, (int) points.get(points.size() - 2).getX(), (int) points.get(points.size() - 2).getY(), (int) points.get(points.size() - 1).getX(), (int) points.get(points.size() - 1).getY());
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any action listeners registered on the panels in question? Cyber-monk is correct; code would help.

Comment: I wonder who up-voted this question

Comment: @cyber-monk Accidentally clicked post too soon. My fault. Added my only listener at the moment (button is non functional until I sort this error. Sorry about that.

Comment: @BillHorvathII Added in my only current listener, as well as how I am adding my panels to the frame.

Comment: Why are you calling repaint() here? It doesn't look like you're modifying anything that would affect the UI, unless the points.add method changes something in the UI (in which case repaint should be called there, not here. But make sure you do so on the event dispatch thread.)

Comment: You're going to have to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not disconnected snippets. What does your initgr() method do?

Answer (score 0):

Add a background color to each of your panels.  Retest your code and see what the colors tell you.  Often in swing if a panel is empty, it will collapse and other panels will grow or shrink to consume to space.  I would look over the rules for which panels gets precedence.  I'm guessing the first added component gets precedence when resizing occurs but I'm not certain and it should be simple to cook up an example to determine the precedence. From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) it looks like:

> The NORTH and SOUTH components may be stretched horizontally; the EAST
>   and WEST components may be stretched vertically; the CENTER component
>   may stretch both horizontally and vertically to fill any space left
>   over.